# How save User data in OneToOneField | Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.11

I have two models(`User` and `Profile`). In `Profile` model as you can see I have `idx` field which I use for sorting. In my project I show list of profiles and admin can sorting them by drag and drop. For thats why I use `idx`. Also this field is invisible and admin dont change its value manually.

**Question**: How edit User data by profile id. As I said before I show list of profiles. Right now I have edit form where I show user data by profile id. Problem raise when I try to submit form after changes.

**models.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idx = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Field for sorting, default=0, blank=True,)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['idx', 'pk']
        db_table = 'user_profile'


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Profile)
def delete_user(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        instance.user.delete()
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py:**

```
class UserEditView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'users/edit_user.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    model = User

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = dict()
        profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        user_edit_form = UserForm(instance=profile.user)
        context = {
            'profile': profile,
            'user_edit_form': user_edit_form
        }
        data['html_user_edit_form'] = render_to_string(
            'users/edit_user.html', context, request=request
        )
        return JsonResponse(data)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        data = dict()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        context = {'users': User.objects.all()}
        data['html_users'] = render_to_string('users/users.html', context)
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**ERROR:**

```
LevelName: WARNING | Module: base | Process: 662 | Thread: 123145371320320 | Message: Not Found: /user/31/edit/
LevelName: WARNING | Module: basehttp | Process: 662 | Thread: 123145371320320 | Message: "POST /user/31/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1800
```

Comment: Where is this error message copied from ? Is it from the server log ?

Comment: I have logging settings and show logs in console (terminal). I use Django's dev server.

Comment: When you delete the Profile it won't delete the User. That is the issue ?

Comment: No, my question is not about it. Delete works correct! When I delete Profile it also delete User account. I have problems with editing. By profile id I need to edit user data which is in user field (OneToOneField).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my mistake.
From url I take id of profile but then in template I need to send id of user.

I just add `context = {'user': profile.user,}` and then use in template `user.id` instead of `profile.id`.